# What is the meaning of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ being $\mathcal{C^k}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What is the meaning of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ being $\mathcal{C^k}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$? I need an explanation for the case $N \geq 2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All partial derivatives up to order $k$ exist and are continuous.

Comment: Is there any restriction as to what happens to partial derivatives of order higher than $k$ ?

Comment: Also wonder what happens to the case of $f : \mathbb{R^N} \to \mathbb{R^M}$ ?

Comment: @Rajesh, no restriction. For the general case, you impose the conditions on all coordinate functions of $f$.

Comment: by no restriction do you mean one or more of them may not exist at some point. Please clarify whether i am getting it correct.

Comment: @Rajesh, being $\mathcal C^k$ has *no* implication on being $\mathcal C^r$ for $r>k$. In other words, $\mathcal C^r \subset \mathcal C^k$ and the inclusion is strict.

Answer (score 2):

The function is $k$ times differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $D^kf$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But defining $D^k f$ when $N>1$ makes this answer harder to understand than the lhf answer...